# Java - remove useless words from text file

Tags: java, text

I have to write a java program that reads a text file line by line and removes the "useless" words like "I," "you," "he," "she," "on," "in,"  ... and so on, keeping all others for a sort of sentiment analysis. As there are a lot, does a dictionary exist of words like those, or do I need to write one by myself?

Comment: Since only you know the *useless* words, then you should write the dictionary by yourself. That's part of your assignment/work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for a list of *stop words*. Such lists are available as references on [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words) on that subject. The first linked list starts like this:

- a
- about
- above
- across
- after
- afterwards
- again

It also contains the words you have mentioned, so it seems to meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I gather that you're supposed to remove all pronouns and prepositions. An easy way would be to make a [set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html) of the strings of all pronouns and prepositions that you want to remove (i.e. `Set<String>`). Then iterate through all of the elements, parsing up the text file for each to remove those words, and putting it back together when you're done.

Comment: Since the words to remove are `String`s, it would be easier to store them in a `Set<String>` for a faster search.